# No mapping found for HTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I just started developing a blog app. It's my first app with Spring, Thymeleaf and Hibernate. I had my index page displaying, then I fiddled with Hibernate settings and persistence layer and suddenly my app won't load.

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and my controller

```
@Controller
public class BlogController {

    @Autowired
    private BlogPostManager blogPostManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPosts(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("postList", blogPostManager.getAllBlogPosts());
        model.addAttribute("blogPost", new BlogPost());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addpost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPost(@ModelAttribute(value = "blogPost")BlogPost blogPost){
        blogPostManager.addBlogPost(blogPost);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

When I try to access my app (deployed to tomcat8 and packaged as war), I get the standard 404 tomcat page and tomcat console prints this warning:

```
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-108]
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP
request with URI [/blog%2D1.0/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

I can post my index.html if needed, but it's a simple hello world with one form. If I comment out the form and leave just hello world, I still get the same error.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: You need a mapping for the servlet, like it says?  Which mapping do you expect will map that servlet to a url path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your url pattern is OK ("/"),but one thing that i see missing in **spring-servlet.xml** file is below line

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your-base-package-path" />
```

I hope after adding above line in your xml file,spring mvc will be able to scan the controller's  and service.

Comment: welp, looking at git history, for some reason I deleted this line. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I only know basic Servlets but I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that your Spring servlet mapping is wrong.  It should be `/*` instead of just `/`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   <<-- CHANGE THIS
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I tried that. It was actually in few answers here, but they all said that you should use `/` instead of `/*`